# How to reference a workbook when working with two workbooks while one of them doesn't have a specific hard coded file name

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple workbooks that contain multiple worksheets. Each workbook is for each person. So I want to merge all sheets into one new workbook and save the workbook for each person individually. I cannot figure out how to switch between a new workbook and the existing one. I do not want to reference the existing file, the one that contains multiple sheets, by file name because the filename for each person varies.

```
    Sub MergeSheets()
Dim i As Integer
Dim Newbook As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim PersonName As String

PersonName = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Person Profile").Range("D3")
Set Newbook = Workbooks.Add
Set ws = Newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Name = "Merged"


ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Person Profile").Activate
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Newbook.Range("A1")


For i = 2 To Sheets.Count
Sheets(i).Activate
UsedRange.Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=ws.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
Next

Newbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\Documents\" + PersonName + ".xls"


End Sub
```

Comment: Open the book via its path and set it to a variable then interact with said variable.

Comment: Where is your "single person" workbooks list to loop through? Maybe you post an example of your starting and ending scenario.

Comment: @user3598756 The macro is not intended to loop through all workbooks. The idea is to open a workbook that needs to be processed and run macro which will create a separate workbook and which will be saved in a path provided in the code. The name for the file will be referenced from one of cell id's in one of the sheets in the workbook that is being processed. I hope it makes sense. Thank you

Comment: @findwindow I would do  that however, each file name to process has unique name. so I am not sure how to open each workbook  via the path and pass it as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the name of the workook

```
Sub test()
    Dim workBook1 As Workbook
    Dim workBook2 As Workbook
    Dim workBook3 As Workbook
    Set workBook1 = Workbooks("Book1") 'If opened
    Set workBook2 = Workbooks("Book3") 'If opened
    'if not opened
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Rui\Documents\Benfica.xlsx"
    set workBook3 = Workbooks("Benfica.xlsx") 
End Sub
```

Comment: That requires hardcoding each book.

Comment: I change the code to the scenario of not opened file